# Using matplotlib to create a histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to use a histogram to plot mass shooting fatalities located at https://www.kaggle.com/zusmani/us-mass-shootings-last-50-years/data. Here is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn


plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
plt.hist(np.sort(shootings['Date']), np.sort(shootings['Total victims'].values))
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Total Victims', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

I'm getting this error each time I do it:

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

**Edit:**

@roganjosh I tried that but then this happens.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3cd3769d1995> in <module>()
      1 plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
----> 2 np.sort(shootings)
      3 plt.hist((shootings['Date']), (shootings['Total victims'].values))
      4 plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
      5 plt.ylabel('Total Victims', fontsize=12)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
    845     else:
    846         a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
--> 847     a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    848     return a
    849 

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to try sort dates and integer values independently; then the x/y coords just get mismatched. You should sort the DataFrame itself and then plot the values

Comment: `shootings['Date']` seems to be strings. You cannot histogram strings. Also `hist` does not take two data arrays, but only one. What is the purpose of the second dataset? Please provide a [mcve] of the issue if you want help here.

Answer (score 0):

`'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`means that in your array you have `int` and `str`. You should look at your shootings array to see which type of data there're in it.